# I want to create a mask of a numpy array, flagging any rows that contain values in another array

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have a numpy array:

```
247 656 6363
13822   13818   30054
10174   25484   6553
6107    2927    6578
2904    6462    3941
16562   8692    16563
25182   6681    25181
6679    6429    3841
```

I want to flag all rows in this array where any of the 3 columns contain numbers from a second array:

```
13822
13818
2927
8692
3841
```

Is this possible?

I would like the results to provide a list or array of all the rows in array 1 which contain one of these values.

I have searched around and tried using `numpy.mask` but to no avail yet. I would ideally like a return of all the row numbers where the row contains values of the second array, so that I can remove these rows later.

Comment: How large is the array in question?
Can you fit it in memory?
Instead of using stuff like masks, I would opt for starting with iteration over the array, checking values(which should work but it won't be efficient), then trying to figure out how to proceed. Show us what you tried, what you searched for.

Comment: I tried this!

mask = np.ma.masked_array(elements, mask=[nodes])

elements is the first array, nodes is the second

My error was:

MaskError: Mask and data not compatible: data size is 203847, mask size is 3830.

Comment: None of the values in your first array exist in the second array. They're not even the right order of magnitude

Comment: I have only given the start of the arrays, as they are quite long!

Comment: ... come on. You're trying to convey the problem to us so you could have just made them up for a [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean). Now I have to ask whether the omission of 815 in your target array is deliberate. Help us to help you.

Comment: Don't get side tracked with the `np.ma.maskedarray` stuff.  What you want is a boolean array that is True where you get matches, or an array of indices where that is True.  For a start, try `first[:,:,None]==Second` which should give you a 3d array boolean array.  Best test that with smaller arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Josh, I'll maybe give you a different sample example so it's easier to understand?

Comment: Yes please and keep it in mind in future. You should show an example input, the expected output (which from your current data is an empty collection, so impossible to verify) and the attempt you made. With the former two, we at least have a chance of meeting your expectation and the third shows that you have put some effort into understanding - then any misconceptions can be addressed along with the answer

Comment: I've updated my question for this!

Comment: Numpty: what is "quite long"? Your example shows arrays of size 8x3 and 5x1, but you say above these are redacted and the actual arrays are much longer (how long? how wide are they?). We need the dimensions NxM and Kx1. (We don't need the actual content, you could use seeded-random data). Otherwise, we can't compare performance.

Comment: Second, it's very confusing what you mean by "flag" when you say *"flag all rows in arr1 where any of the 3 cols contain numbers from array2... return their row-indices... so I can remove these rows later."* Why not just remove (drop) them all in one step? And you don't necessarily need their row-indices to do that, you could just do it directly in one step. So unless you can explain your reason for needing to do further processing on the whole of arr1 before you drop those rows,  why don't we just drop them immediately?

Answer (score 2):

I'm stealing @hpaulj's example first, so credit for that. Then just use [`isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html).

```
import numpy as np

first = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)
second = np.array([4,3,1,13])
res = np.isin(first, second)

print(res.any(axis=1))
```

I decided to time this out and the difference is astronomical:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

first = np.arange(30000).reshape(-1,3)
second = np.random.randint(0, 30000, size=1000)

def add_dimension(first, second):
    res = (first[:,:,None]==second).any(axis=(1,2))
    return res
    
def with_isin(first, second):
    res = np.isin(first, second).any(axis=1)
    return res
    
print("With dimension:",timeit.timeit(lambda: add_dimension(first, second), number=1000))
print("With isin", timeit.timeit(lambda: with_isin(first, second), number=1000))

a = add_dimension(first, second)
b = with_isin(first, second)
print(np.array_equal(a, b))
```

This gives me:

```
With dimension: 15.245749666937627
With isin 0.18458845792338252
True
```

Comment: From some quick tests, it looks like: `isin` is faster when: `len(second) >= 2` for `len(first) > 3000`. Underneath 3000 rows, `add_dimension` can be faster for small-sized `second` arrays. For example, for `len(first) == 300` the break-even point is `len(second) > 100`.

Answer (score 1):

One, using a 3d comparison array.

A pair of sample arrays:

```
In [184]: first = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3); second = np.array([4,3,1,13])

In [185]: first, second
Out[185]: 
(array([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14]]),
 array([ 4,  3,  1, 13]))
```

Use numpy broadcasting to compare the 2, the result is 3d:

```
In [186]: first[:,:,None]==second
Out[186]: 
array([[[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False,  True, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False, False]]])
```

Now check for the desired combination of True.  For all rows of `first` with at least one True:

```
In [187]: (first[:,:,None]==second).any(axis=1)
Out[187]: 
array([[False, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

test both the last row of `first`, and `second` (axis 2):

```
In [188]: (first[:,:,None]==second).any(axis=(1,2))
Out[188]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True])
```

and row indices:

```
In [189]: np.nonzero(_)
Out[189]: (array([0, 1, 4], dtype=int64),)
```

### edit

For my small exmple, using `isin`:

```
In [191]: np.isin(first,second)
Out[191]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])

In [192]: np.isin(first,second).any(axis=1)
Out[192]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True])

In [193]: timeit np.isin(first,second).any(axis=1)
170 µs ± 338 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [194]: timeit (first[:,:,None]==second).any(axis=(1,2))
17.1 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

and testing an iteration by columns:

```
In [199]: timeit np.any([(first[:,i,None]==second).any(axis=1) for i in range(3)], axis=0)
84.1 µs ± 331 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

But as with most timings, they can scale differently with large examples.

Comment: I don't know what the time complexity of this is but the timings in my answer surprised me (I thought it would win, but not by orders of magnitude). I don't think I've messed up in the timings but please check my work.

Comment: `isin` uses `in1d`, which in turn uses a sort and `unique` approach (read the source).. Mine can be slowed down memory use the 3d intermediate array. A variate on mine is to iterate on 3 columns.  For large arrays, a few iterations can be faster.

Comment: Why would anyone use `numpy` for 5 rows of data?

Comment: At least on my laptop, the break-even point is about 30 items in `first`